# Firebase Storage URL access only in my Firebase hosted website

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I need to access an image in my Firebase storage without exposing the URL or being only accessed on my website.

The problem is that the image is the background of my website and I can't use Auth to secure it.

I can't afford to repeatedly being accessed by someone and ended up billing me.

I've tried `gsReference` but when getting the image it uses `gsReference.getDownloadURL()` and puts it in the CSS file and if I inspect and copy-paste the URL in another tab, it can read the image.

Comment: im using firebase hosting to host my website, if there's any way to just reference it locally like in HTML that would be great

Comment: If the image is the background of your website, is there a reason you can't deploy it with your website?

Comment: @samthecodingman does firebase storage don't bill if you exceed the limit on reading files?

Comment: If you exceed the Spark plan limits, any requests will simply error-out based on [this entry in the FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#pricing-exceed-3). You shouldn't be billed, but depending on a case-by-case basis, they may charge you if you make too many blocked requests. I haven't ever hit the quota limit on a Spark plan (by the time I'm hitting the free tier limits, I've already transitioned to a paid Blaze plan), so I'm not sure what the actual error returned is. I would assume you would get a `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests` response.

Answer (score 1):

If you generate a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for a file in Cloud Storage, it will be accessible by anyone with that URL from anywhere on the internet.

If you need to control access to a file in Cloud Storage, don't use download URLs. Instead, use Firebase Authentication along with the Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK to download files that are protected by [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/) that allow access for a given user who is logged in. This is the only way to limit downloads.

Comment: but you need to be authenticated to access the files right? the problem is its the background image of my website and it will not load

Comment: yes, what i did is use the anonymous login for visitors, and put read/write if auth != null